# Create multidimensional array with one unknown length

Tags: numpy, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I do not know yet the length of the first dimension but I do know the lengths of the second and the third dimension. How can I set up such an array?

```
import numpy as np
mdi=-1e30
print(np.shape(TheData)) #(540, 36, 72)
NYears = np.int(len(TheData[:,0,0])/12)
OutputData = np.empty(([],36,72))
OutputData.fill(mdi)
```

I am using three for loops to fill my OutputData array:

```
for lt in range(36):
        for ln in range(72):
                MonthArray = np.reshape(TheData[:,lt,ln],(NYears,12))
                for yr in range(NYears):
                        gotdata = np.where(MonthArray[yr,SeasonInfo] > mdi)
                        SubArray = MonthArray[yr,SeasonInfo[gotdata]]
                        OutputData = np.append(OutputData,SubArray)
                OutputData[yr,lt,ln] = OutputData
```

I expect the OutputData have a shape of (approx. 176,36,72).

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I am not quite sure which loop to add the OutputData[yr,lt,ln] = OutputData, or if only OutputData[lt,ln] = OutputData would do it as well.

Comment: you can't. All dimensions must be specified.  And avoid `np.append`!

Comment: If I am not going for 36 x 72 grid boxes, but only 1 single time series, I use OutputData = np.array([]) to introduce my array of unknown length. After the "for yr in range(NYears)" loop I get a np.shape(OutputData) = (134,). How do you recommend to solve this for 36 x 72 grid boxes?

Comment: `np.array([])` is not an array of unknown length.  Check its shape.  `np.array` is not `np.empty` either.  Inputs are different,

Comment: What's `NYears`?  `TheData`?

Comment: NYears is the number of years; it's the length of the first dimension of TheData. The second dimension are the latitudes, the last the longitudes.

Comment: I got around the problem, using a `SubArray = []` and `SubArray = MonthArray[yr,SeasonInfo[gotdata]]`, the function `SubOutputData = np.append(SubOutputData,SubArray)` and put the value in the main array `OutputData[:,lt,ln] = SubOutputData`. - However, this is not a straight forward way and my question 'I do not know yet the length of the first dimension but I do know the lengths of the second and the third dimension. How can I set up such an array?' is not answered yet.

Comment: It's hard to tell how the size of `OutputData` relates to the inputs.  At first glance I though it was just (NYears, 36,72), but then I see some complicated use of `where`.  I not interested decoding that loop, and obviously can't run it myself.  So all I'll add now is that repeated list appends are much better than `np.append`.  I have recommended that many times on SO.